# Why does the screen dim when a DialogFragment that contains a GLSurfaceView is shown?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to accomplish this, but I want a popup with a GLSurfaceView. So I created a dialogFragment and in its onCreateView method I return my glSurfaceView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = new mGLSurfaceView(this.getDialog().getContext());
    return mView;
}
```

When the DialogFragment is shown the entire screen dims, not just the background. This does not happen when I return a LinearLayout with a TextView inside.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the way GLSurfaceView works - the View part of GLSurfaceView is just a transparent container, and the rendering is done on Surface that sits below the Layout (and below the Layout for the Activity that has triggered the DialogFragment). Now when the DialogFragment is created, there is a "dimming layer" inserted between the DialogFragment and the parent Activity, to bring focus to the DialogFragment. This dimming layer ends up sitting between the transparent-View-part of GLSurfaceView, but above the rendering Surface, which explains why the entire screen appears to dim.

You can fix this by calling setZOrderOnTop(true) when you create your GLSurfaceView - this will force the rendering Surface to sit above all other views in the DialogFragment Layout, so above the dimming layer.